# Enviar minutos al Web.Config para mantener la sesión ( timeout) asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sesiones

Como hacer para enviar un tiempo defino por el usuario al momento de iniciar sesión
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al verficar el usuario pueda enviarme ese valor al timeout="60" del Web.Config.

```
        public ActionResult VerificaUsuario(UsuarioModel susuario, FormCollection collection)
        {
                    int TiempoSesion = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["TiempoSesion"]);
}
```

Estoy trayendolo en un FormColletion el tiempo, llega todo, lo que no puedo es enviarlo.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Usuario/VerificaUsuario" timeout="10" defaultUrl="~/Usuario/VerificaUsuario" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="10" />
```

Enxiste alguna otra forma para hacer esto ???

Comment: no estoy del todo seguro pero creo que el objeto `Session` es equivalente a tu `sessionState` del web config, por lo que podrías popner `Session.Timeout = 10;` por ejemplo (valor en minutos)

Comment: @LPZadkiel exacto un valor en minutos